# Node.js: Creating incremental watchfile listeners on client connect and removing them respectively

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a client connection event, which when fires, starts watching a file. When a second client connects, the same file is watched again. (`fs.watchFile()` is used)

On the client disconnection event, the file is unwatched. (`fs.unwatchFile()` is used) So if the first client disconnects, the file is also unwatched for the second client.

How do I work around this? I've tried using the listener function of `fs.watchfile` and `fs.unwatchFile()` but I don't know how to name each listener differently on a client connect.

From what I know, creating a listener is done by assigning a variable like such:

```
var listener1 = function (curr, prev) {
  console.log('touched 1');
});
```

Then the listener can be watched or unwatched:

```
fs.watchfile('data.log', listener1);
fs.unwatchFile('data.log', listener1);
```

How do I name that listener uniquely every time a client connects? So then I can unwatch the file *by listener* instead of by file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object, keyed by whatever you're using to identify clients, whose values are the individual listeners:

```
var listeners = {};
...
// When client connects
listeners[clientId] = function(curr, prev) {
...
};
fs.watchfile('data.log', listeners[clientId]);
...
// When client disconnects
fs.unwatchfile('data.log', listeners[clientId]);
```

As a general rule, if you find yourself wanting a bunch of similarly-named variables, one for each instance of something, what you really want is a data structure like an array or object.

Comment: I'm assuming that `clientId` is determined by whatever code handles a connection being established, and is unique to that connection. The only restriction is that it has to be usable as an object key.